# What is this pipe sticking out of the ground?

Tags: leak, pvc, sprinkler-system, irrigation

This is connected to my sprinkler system. It has a crack in the side and leaks when the water to the sprinkler system is turned on, even when the sprinkler system isn’t running. Does anyone know what it is, and if I can fix it by repairing the pipe or if there is an issue somewhere else in the system?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably a stub-out for a drip irrigation line. You’d cut it off slightly below grade, hookup a drip line and run the drip irrigation line on top of the ground.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a water supply meant to extend existing but before the valve so that is why it is leaking when off or if its a slight leak after water has been turned on, it maybe just water syphoning for what is left in the lines. Either way I would shut off your water and replace the area or cut it low and cap it.